# Running OpenCL using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, opencl

I'm a newbie in OpenCL, so far I referred Dr. Dobbs tutorials for OpenCL and few others and ran it on Ubuntu which worked very well but those same codes won't/refuse to work on windows using Visual Studio with all required Environment Variables set correctly. 
I'm using 980M with CUDA SDK 8 on vs 2015. I have two files, one in C and another is a kernel(cl) file. Whenever I add both .c & .cl files, the program refuses to run by throwing errors like Can't find program files and things like that. However, if I write the kernel file within C file, it works sometimes say 1 out of 3. The same program works fine on my PC running Ubuntu 16 and another PC with AMD card running on Ubuntu 16. 
The program I'm trying to run is vector addition written in C.
I've attached the link to the code.
[OpenCL vector addition](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By3E-hlojnXVQUcxZ0l0OGR4Ymc)

add_numbers.c

```
 #define PROGRAM_FILE "add_numbers.cl"
 #define KERNEL_FUNC "vecAdd"

 #include <math.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #ifdef __linux
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <fcntl.h> 

 #endif // __linux


#ifdef MAC
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

/* Find a GPU or CPU associated with the first available platform */
cl_device_id create_device() {

   cl_platform_id platform;
   cl_device_id dev;
   int err;

   /* Identify a platform */
   err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't identify a platform");
      exit(1);
   } 

   /* Access a device */
   err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &dev, NULL);
 if(err == CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND) {
      err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &dev, NULL);
   }
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't access any devices");
      exit(1);   
   }

   return dev;
}

/* Create program from a file and compile it */
cl_program build_program(cl_context ctx, cl_device_id dev, const char* filename) {

   cl_program program;
   FILE *program_handle;
   char *program_buffer, *program_log;
   size_t program_size, log_size;
   int err;

   /* Read program file and place content into buffer */
   program_handle = fopen(filename, "r");
   if(program_handle == NULL) {
      perror("Couldn't find the program file");
      exit(1);
   }
   fseek(program_handle, 0, SEEK_END);
   program_size = ftell(program_handle);
   rewind(program_handle);
   program_buffer = (char*)malloc(program_size + 1);
   program_buffer[program_size] = '\0';
   fread(program_buffer, sizeof(char), program_size, program_handle);
   fclose(program_handle);

   /* Create program from file */
   program = clCreateProgramWithSource(ctx, 1, 
      (const char**)&program_buffer, &program_size, &err);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't create the program");
      exit(1);
   }
   free(program_buffer);

   /* Build program */
   err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
   if(err < 0) {

      /* Find size of log and print to std output */
      clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, dev, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 
            0, NULL, &log_size);
      program_log = (char*) malloc(log_size + 1);
      program_log[log_size] = '\0';
      clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, dev, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 
            log_size + 1, program_log, NULL);
      printf("%s\n", program_log);
      free(program_log);
      exit(1);
   }

   return program;
}

int main() {

   /* OpenCL structures */
   cl_device_id device;
   cl_context context;
   cl_program program;
   cl_kernel kernel;
   cl_command_queue queue;
   cl_device_type dev_type; //new
  // cl_int i, j, err;
   size_t local_size, global_size;


   // vector add pgm
// Length of vectors
    unsigned int n = 1000000;

    // Host input vectors
    double *h_a;
    double *h_b;
    // Host output vector
    double *h_c;

    // Device input buffers
    cl_mem d_a;
    cl_mem d_b;
    // Device output buffer
    cl_mem d_c;

    // Size, in bytes, of each vector
    size_t bytes = n*sizeof(double);

    // Allocate memory for each vector on host
    h_a = (double *)malloc(bytes);
    h_b = (double *)malloc(bytes);
    h_c = (double *)malloc(bytes);

    // Initialize vectors on host
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        /*h_a[i] = sinf(i)*sinf(i);
        h_b[i] = cosf(i)*cosf(i);*/
        h_a[i] = i+1; 
        h_b[i] = i+2; 
    }

  //  size_t globalSize, localSize;
    cl_int err;

    // Number of work items in each local work group
    local_size = 64;

    // Number of total work items - localSize must be devisor
    global_size = (n/local_size)*local_size;

   /* Create device and context */
   device = create_device();
   context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &err);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't create a context");
      exit(1);   
   }

   /* Build program */
   program = build_program(context, device, PROGRAM_FILE);

   /* Create data buffer */
     input_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY |
         CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float), data, &err);
   sum_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE |
         CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, num_groups * sizeof(float), sum, &err);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't create a buffer");
      exit(1);   
   };*/
   //input buffers
    d_a = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, bytes, NULL, NULL);
    d_b = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, bytes, NULL, NULL);
    d_c = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, bytes, NULL, NULL);

   /* Create a command queue */
   queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, 0, &err);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't create a command queue");
      exit(1);   
   };

   /* Create a kernel */
   kernel = clCreateKernel(program, KERNEL_FUNC, &err);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't create a kernel");
      exit(1);
   };

  // Newer args under test
  err  = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &d_a);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &d_b);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &d_c);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(unsigned int), &n);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't create a kernel argument");
      exit(1);
   }

   /* Enqueue kernel */
   err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_size, 
         &local_size, 0, NULL, NULL); 
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't enqueue the kernel");
      exit(1);
   }

   /* Read the kernel's output */
        err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, d_c, CL_TRUE, 0,
                                bytes, h_c, 0, NULL, NULL );

   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't read the buffer");
      exit(1);
   }
   //cl_device_type dev_type;
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_TYPE, sizeof(dev_type), &dev_type, NULL);
if (dev_type == CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU) {
    puts("I'm 100% sure this device is a GPU");
    }
    else
    puts("Device is CPU\n");

// Sum calc.

double sum = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        //sum += h_c[i];
       sum = h_a[i] + h_b[i];
    printf("final result: %lf\n",(sum/n));


   /* Deallocate resources */
   clReleaseMemObject(d_a);
    clReleaseMemObject(d_b);
    clReleaseMemObject(d_c);
   clReleaseKernel(kernel);
   clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
   clReleaseProgram(program);
   clReleaseContext(context);
   return 0;
}
```

add_number.cl kernel file

```
__kernel void vecAdd(  __global double *a,                    
                       __global double *b,                
                       __global double *c,                     
                       const unsigned int n)                    
    {      
        #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 :enable                                                    
    //Get our global thread ID                               
    int id = get_global_id(0);                       

    //Make sure we do not go out of bounds                  
        if (id < n)                                            
        c[id] = a[id] + b[id];                               

    }
```

Comment: Are you using the correct relative path for the .cl file compilation? Perhaps try using the absolute path as a test.

Comment: **Never** post links to your code, always include it in your question. In this case I can't even look at it as you didn't give the correct permissions.

Comment: @MichaelKissner: How I do set relative and absolute paths in VS? I added these code as **Existing items** in  **source files** section